# Calculating total resistance for resistor network circuit

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, resistance

[image: Total resistance?]

I'm very lost in my ECE class right now and I was hoping someone could help me out and explain what they're doing. I was asked to calculate the total resistance.  After getting that, I was asked to calculate the \$i_2(t)\$ in terms of \$R\$ and \$i_S(t)\$.  I am so lost and any help in explaining this to me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for the total resistance across the \$a\$ and \$b\$ terminals?

Comment: @Null Yes, I am.  I am looking for the Req of the entire circuit.

Comment: What if you replace the current source with a short. Can you calculate the equivalent resistance then? Can you replace a parallel combination of two resistors with one equivalent resistor?

Comment: Is Req the resistance seen across the a,b terminals, or is it the resistance seen by the current source?  They are _not_ the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the equivalent resistance across terminals \$a\$ and \$b\$ first set the independent sources to zero. In this case you have a current source so when it is set to zero it is equivalent to an open circuit (if it was a voltage source then it would be equivalent to a short circuit). Your circuit now looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBwPMq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_1\$ is in series with an open circuit so it can be ignored. You have three remaining resistors. \$R_2\$ is in series with \$R_3\$ so their combined resistance is \$2R\$. This resistance is in parallel with \$R_4\$ so

$$R_{eq} = 2R \parallel R_4 = 2R \parallel R = \frac{2R^2}{2R + R} = \frac{2}{3}R$$

To find \$i_2(t)\$ you can use a current divider. Since \$a\$ and \$b\$ are open terminals the current through \$R_3\$ is simply \$i_2(t)\$, and the equivalent resistance in this path is \$R_3 + R_4 = 2R\$. By KCL at the node between \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, and \$R_3\$:

$$i_S(t) = i_1(t) + i_2(t)$$

The current divider at this node gives

$$i_2(t) = \frac{R_2}{R_3 + R_4 + R_2}i_S(t) = \frac{R}{3R}i_S(t) = \frac{1}{3}i_S(t)$$

Comment: You might want to re-visit the second half of this answer...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thanks for the catch. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Null Thank you very much for clearing this up.  It makes a lot more sense to me now!